Pandas: Groupby columns and propagate the false value from the bottommost node to the upmost
Here is the dataframe:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
                   "node": np.repeat([0, 1, 2, 3], 3),
                   "type": np.tile(['A', 'B', 'C'], 4),
                   "flag": [True, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, False, True, True]
                  })

df.sort_values(by=['type', 'node'], ascending=True, inplace=True)

which looks like:
  node type flag
0   0   A   True
3   1   A   True
6   2   A   True
9   3   A   False
1   0   B   True
4   1   B   True
7   2   B   True
10  3   B   True
2   0   C   True
5   1   C   False
8   2   C   True
11  3   C   True

What I want to do is to find if in any type there is a False flag, and if so get the bottommost node, and set the all the upper node's flag to False. The result would be like:
  node type flag
0   0   A   False
3   1   A   False
6   2   A   False
9   3   A   False
1   0   B   True
4   1   B   True
7   2   B   True
10  3   B   True
2   0   C   False
5   1   C   False
8   2   C   True
11  3   C   True

In this case, type A got a False at node 3, so node 1, 2 should both be set to False; type B got no False, skip; type C got a False at node 1, so node 0 should be set to False.
What I did now is
gp = df.groupby(['type'])
result_indices = []
for name, group in gp:
    false_index = group[group['flag'] == False].index
    if len(false_index) > 0:
        result_indices.extend(group.index[group.index < false_index[-1]])

df.loc[result_indices, 'flag'] = False

Any better solutions that can avoid the for loop? (for better efficiency), I once tried methods like mask or where but have no idea how to write such a complex filter.
I can extract the False index like these:
df.sort_values(by=['type', 'node'], ascending=[True, False], inplace=True)
gp = df[df['flag'] == False].groupby('type').head(1).index

but don't know how to forward.

There is an inconsistency in your question: the last element in the definition of "flag" (index 11) is False, while it is shown in the printout (last row) as True.

@simon sorry, have fixed that.

Here's one approach:

Reverse your df with [::-1], apply df.groupby on 'type', get groupby.cummin for 'flag', and reverse back.

df['flag'] = df[::-1].groupby('type')['flag'].cummin()[::-1]

df

    node type   flag
0      0    A  False
3      1    A  False
6      2    A  False
9      3    A  False
1      0    B   True
4      1    B   True
7      2    B   True
10     3    B   True
2      0    C  False
5      1    C  False
8      2    C   True
11     3    C   True


I did not know there was cummin() – This makes everything so much simpler :D Have my upvote!

very cool one liner.

Inspired by the answer of @simon I find it can be simplified a bit without reversing:  df.sort_values(by=['type', 'node'], ascending=[True, False], inplace=True) and then use cumprod to get that:  df["propagated"] = df.groupby("type")["flag"].cumprod().astype(bool)

@chapayev I undeleted my answer, because you just referred to it. I still think this answer here is the way better one (shorter, more straightforward).

@chapayev I like the solution of your comment above also quite a bit. Suggestions: (1) you can also directly use cummin() (it preserves the type) rather than cumprod().astype(bool) (so: df.sort_values(by=['type', 'node'], ascending=[True, False], inplace=True); df["propagated"] = df.groupby("type")["flag"].cummin()), (2) you could formulate it as another answer to your question rather than as a comment.

@chapayev: if you adjust the sort, it is possible with .cummin() without reversing the df, as @simon just mentioned. I assumed that the OP wants to keep the sort order. If not, that would be easier of course.

@ouroboros1 Note that chapayev is OP.

@simon oops, my bad :)

@ouroboros1 You still have a point though, as this aspect (i.e. importance of sorting order) is not clear from the question.

@chapayev: come to think of it, df[::-1].groupby('type')['flag'].cummin()[::-1] will already work on the initial, still otherwise unsorted, df.

Update: After realizing from @ouroboros1's answer that cummin() exists, I would consider the answer below obsolete, as it is unnecessarily complicated. I just left it here for reference, because it was referred to in a comment.
You can (mis)use cumsum() for propagation: With a cumulative sum, you can propagate True values from top to bottom; for example, np.cumsum([False, True, True, False]).astype(bool) produces [False,  True,  True,  True]. What is different in your case is that you want to propagate False values from bottom to top. We can still use cumsum() though:

Negate the values of interest.
Reverse the order of values.
Calculate cumsum().
Re-reverse the order of values.
Convert back to bool and negate result.

This could look as follows:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
                   "node": np.repeat([0, 1, 2, 3], 3),
                   "type": np.tile(['A', 'B', 'C'], 4),
                   "flag": [True, True, True, True, True, False,
                            True, True, True, False, True, True]
                  })

df.sort_values(by=['type', 'node'], ascending=True, inplace=True)

# Reverse order of values
df_rev_neg = df.iloc[::-1]
# Negate values of interest
df_rev_neg["flag"] = ~df_rev_neg["flag"]
# Calculate grouped `cumsum()`, convert back to `bool`, negate values again
df["propagated"] = ~df_rev_neg.groupby("type")["flag"].cumsum().astype(bool)
print(df)

Which prints:
    node type   flag  propagated
0      0    A   True       False
3      1    A   True       False
6      2    A   True       False
9      3    A  False       False
1      0    B   True        True
4      1    B   True        True
7      2    B   True        True
10     3    B   True        True
2      0    C   True       False
5      1    C  False       False
8      2    C   True        True
11     3    C   True        True

Here we did not explicitly need to re-reverse the order of values (step 4), as we carried the frame's index along throughout.
